# Visual paradigm, cant use persistence inheritance on a DCD

Tags: java, inheritance, uml, persistence, visual-paradigm

I am trying to have a simple inheritance with visual paradigm on a DCD.

However every time i try to use update to code it doesn't generate any of the classes used in that inheritance (doesn't generate user, student, bpcoordinator, promotor). It generates everything else fine.

Visual paradigm doesn't throw any errors so i assume everything succeeded but this is not the case.

User should be a MappedSuperclass and student, bpcoordinator, promotor should be subclasses inheriting from the User superclass.

[image: dcd]

Comment: Do you generate straight into the place where your IDE project resides ? If yes, please check if files are properly refreshed by IDE. I can't really try this for you, becase I've only subscribed to modeler version of VP. Which version are you using ?

Comment: I am using Visual Paradigm for UML v10.4. Yes i generate it using the ide integration to netbeans. Files are properly refreshed

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the inheritance with 3 different generalizations instead of one combined.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).